# Highcharts - Only Returning One Date on xAxis

Tags: highcharts

In my area chart I have three series which are presorted chronologically. This is what I am currently getting to display:

[image]

I'm using React which is why you see multiple renders, just ignore that. My dates that I am returning for the xAxis are in order but I'm only getting one. Why is that? Here is my code (using React Highcharts but it shouldn't matter I don't think):

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'datetime',
  labels: {
    formatter: function() {
      const dayStr = moment.unix(this.value).format('D');
      const monthStr = moment.unix(this.value).format('M');
      console.log(`${monthStr}/${dayStr}`, this.value);

      return `${monthStr}/${dayStr}`;
    },
    align: 'left',
    style: { "color": "#FFFFFF" }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Date',
    style: { "color": "#FFFFFF" }
  }
},
```

As you can see my formatter function is returning multiple dates but only one displays.

Comment: Maybe there is not enough place for the second label, try without `align: 'left',`

Comment: Awesome. I removed that and got a second date to display. Rest must not be showing due to space

Answer (score 1):

By default Highcharts algorithms decide which ticks to display (labels are drawn where the ticks are). Also some labels might be omitted when there's no enough space to place them.

Use `tickPositions` to force Highcharts to draw given ticks. You can also try `tickPositioner` to modify the ticks generated automatically.

**API references:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositions
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositioner